# Should re-routing be wrapped into an action?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, action, url-routing, mantrajs

The general question I am facing is related to action design strategies: When and how to invoke actions and when not?

In [Mantra](https://mantrajs.com/) (which uses [React](https://github.com/facebook/react) for its front-end and [Meteor's FlowRouter](https://github.com/kadirahq/flow-router) for routing), I have a UI component containing a [ListItem](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/list).

If I want to re-route to the item's own page in `onClick`, what would be the best strategy?

I am thinking:

1. Add a container and add a `gotoPage` function to `props` which invokes [`FlowRouter.go`](https://github.com/kadirahq/flow-router#flowroutergopathdef-params-queryparams).
2. Invoke `gotoPage` in the UI's `onClick` event.

Does this suffice, or should I add an action for this? I imagine in order to have actions compose a complete and replayable log of all things that have happened, an action must be created. It would be crucial in order to play back all the things a user has done. But at the same time, I am thinking: using `href` without generating an action seems Ok as well. Is "replayability" not generally desirable, do URL changes somehow create actions implicitly or is there some other thing that I am not getting?

Sorry but I am new to the action game :)

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Added simple example to bind a single argument to the action function.

I think there is a plethora of solutions to this problem, but I'll try to describe what I usually do (the written code is not tested). Let's say you have the following list item component `components/list_item.js`:

```
import React from 'react';

class ListItem extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const { clickHandler, label } = this.props;
    return <li onClick={clickHandler}>{label}</li>;
  }

}

// add default props and propTypes here...

export ListItem;
```

and a list wrapper component `components/list.js`:

```
import React from 'react';

import ListItem from './list_item.js';

class List extends React.Component {

  renderItem({ clickHandler, label, arg }) {
    return <ListItem clickHandler={arg ? this.props[clickHandler].bind(this, arg) : this.props[clickHandler]} label={label} />;
  }

  renderList() {
    const { items } = this.props;

    return items.map((item) => {
      return renderItem(item);
    });
  }

  render() {
    return <ul>{this.renderList()}</ul>;
  }

}

// add default props and propTypes here...

export List;
```

If I want to create a new list I would just create a new container as follows `containers/my_list.js`:

```
import List from '../components/list';
import {useDeps, composeWithTracker, composeAll} from 'mantra-core';

export const composer = ({}, onData) => {

  const items = [
    {
      clickHandler: 'goto',
      label: 'Goto document',
      arg: 'MyRoute'
    },
    {
      clickHandler: 'remove',
      label: 'Remove document'
    }
  ];

  onData(null, {items});
};

export const depsMapper = (context, actions) => ({
  goto: actions.myList.goto,
  remove: actions.myList.remove,
  context: () => context
});

export default composeAll(
  composeWithTracker(composer),
  useDeps(depsMapper)
)(List);
```

This container is linked to for instance these actions `actions/my_list.js`:

```
export default {

  goto({ FlowRouter }, route) {
    FlowRouter.go(route);
  },

  remove({ Collections }, _id) {
    Collections.Documents.remove({ _id })
  }

}
```

Using this pattern create a generic structure of our list. Let me know if you find this pattern useful and if you have any improvements on my current solution. You can bind arguments to the click handlers as well while designing the container (not illustrated in the above example).

Comment: So, the answer is:  1) One still should create an action for every routing attempt? And 2) In fact, one should create a specific action for every URL you want to go to, rather than having a generic routing action for any URL? If so: q1) Would you even allow linkage using `<a href=...`, seeing how this would not create an action (it seems inconsistent to have some routing trigger an action and some not)? and q2) What is the advantage of having a single action for every url instead of sharing one action between URLs?

Comment: No need to create a new action for every URL, with the depsMapper you can link to whatever action you want. I usually put actions that are used frequently in an own file called `shared.js` (or something similar) and use it throughout the module. So `goto: actions.myList.goto` could be for example: `goto: actions.shared.goto`. I see now that my example is not illustrating how to bind arguments to the action function, I'll update with a simple example.